# access application controller in view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a action in application controller

```
def is_customer_logged_in?
    !!session[:customer_id]
  end
```

And in my view am trying to access the application_controller action like this

```
<% unless is_customer_logged_in? %>
    some functions
<% end %>
```

The above code is a partial layouts.

This is the error message I am facing

```
undefined method `is_customer_logged_in?' for #<#<Class:0xb51a5300>:0xb5616484>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define it to be a helper method and you should be able to access that method in the view.

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def is_customer_logged_in?
    !!session[:customer_id]
  end

  helper_method :is_customer_logged_in?
end
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to define it as a helper. Why it is not working in application_controller can you explain i cant understand

Comment: @Setout, yes to make a controller method available to the view it's necessary to declare it as a helper.  Please have a look at this doc: http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods:helper_method

Answer (score 0):

try `helper_method: is_customer_logged_in?`